# How to check if you tap over a specific class in reactjs

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have the following code inside a chart component in order to check if when I'm clicking on the chart the cursor is over a label from the chart based on label className.

```
<LineChart 
  onMouseDown={(e) => {
    if ($('.labelBtn:hover').length != 0 ) {
      console.log("over btn");
    } else {
      console.log("not over btn");
      try{
        setRefAreaLeft(e.activeLabel);
      } catch {
        console.log("Click out of chart area");
      }
    } 
  }}
/>
```

The problem with this implementation is that it doesn't work on mobile. If I tap over a label on a mobile device the console log will be "not over btn". How can I check both tap and hover action with jquery or other method?

Comment: I will strongly suggest not to use `jQuery` with `react` [More info](https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/if-you-think-you-need-jquery-in-your-react-app-you-re-doing-it-wrong-77899ed7217e)

Comment: I know is not the best approach but i couldn't find another solution for what i need.

Comment: Mobile browsers don't generally have mice, this is why the touch and pointer event handlers also exist, you may need to implement other forms of input event handling.

Comment: I'm using the rechart library for charts in my app and the only events that are supported inside the component are mouse events, without touch events...